# How do you get a stream details using Gst 1.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, streaming, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I want to create a python file that will output details of a audio stream. I found a good example (https://blogs.gnome.org/uraeus/2011/01/17/back-on-transmageddon-and-new-gstreamer-features/) but it uses GST 0.10 for my project I need Gstreamer 1.0. Below is the code I have done so far but it dosent really work as it should. Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, time, thread
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstPbutils', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, GLib, Gst, GstPbutils, GstTag
from gi.repository.GstPbutils import DiscovererAudioInfo,DiscovererStreamInfo, DiscovererInfo
Gst.init(None)
GObject.threads_init()

class discover:
def __init__(self):
    print"..starting \n"
    self.audiostreams=[]
    self.error = None

def on_discovered(discoverer, ismedia, infile):
    print '\non_discovered:', infile
    discoverer.print_info()

def set_file(self,file):
    self.file_uri=(file)

    discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer.new(10 * Gst.SECOND)
    self.info = discoverer.discover_uri(self.file_uri)
    discoverer.connect('discovered',self.on_discovered)
    print self.info.get_caps()


    self.streaminfo=self.info.get_stream_info()
    self.duration= (self.info.get_duration()/1000000000.0)
    self.container = self.streaminfo.get_caps()
    seekbool = self.info.get_seekable()
    if seekbool is True:
            self.seekable="Yes"
    else:
            self.seekable="No"
    audiostreamcounter=-1

    for i in self.info.get_stream_list():
        audiostreamcounter=audiostreamcounter+1
        if isinstance(i, GstPbutils.DiscovererAudioInfo):
            audiocaps=i.get_caps()
            self.audiostreams.append( self.info.get_codec_description(audiocaps))
            self.audiotags=i.get_tags()

def discover(self, uri):
   self.discovered.discover_uri_async(uri)

def create_report(self):
    # Create properties report
    print "Analyzing " + str(self.file_uri)
    print "Topology:"
    print "  container: " + gst.pbutils.get_codec_description(self.container)
    beancounter=0
    for item in self.audiostreams:
            beancounter=beancounter+1
            print "    audio stream " +str(beancounter) + ": " + self.audiostreams[beancounter-1]
            print "Properties:"
            print "  Duration: " + str(self.duration)
            print "  Seekable: " + str(self.seekable)
            print "  Audio Tags: "
            audiofile_tags = {}
            for akey in self.audiotags.keys():
                    audiofile_tags[akey] = self.audiotags[akey]
                    print "      " + akey, '\t', self.audiotags[akey]

    if __name__=="__main__":
       # if len(sys.argv)>1:
            #file = sys.argv[1]
            file = 'http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio4fm_mf_p?s=1455176207&e=1455190607&h=139a4cf601e4a2edf77bf475b$
            #pwd = os.getcwd()
            #filepath = os.path.join(pwd,file)
            discovering = discover()
            discovering.set_file(file)
            discovering.create_report()
```

Comment: Can you share the errors you get when trying to use with gstreamer 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

The changes in Application side are minimal so it is more a matter of running and fixing what is wrong.

This should help on the changes:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/docs/random/porting-to-1.0.txt
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0

The C API can be, usually, directly mapped to python. Once you let us know what exactly doesn't work a more precise answer can be given.